# r fill a dataframe with parallel code

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have written a R function which follows this structure:

```
output <- data.frame(...) # declare the appropriate dataframe
     for (files in folder)
         for (i in loop2)
               for (j in loop3)
                    res <- ... # compute some result
                    name <- ... # compute some name for the current row
                    output <-  rbind(output,res)  # Fill the data frame...
                    rownames(output)[nrow(output)]<-rowname # ... with a specific row name
```

Apparently, it is terrible to do that in R. I would like to make this treatment parallel, but I don't know how to start. Any idea ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To help with the inner loops we would need to know more about the structure of your data and what you are doing with it to make useful suggestions.  Probably you would end up using `lapply` or `sapply`.

For the outer loop the `foreach` package may get you started.  It does the parallelization for you with syntax that looks like a for loop, just use `rbind` for the tool to combine the results.

In general, it is probably more efficient to assign the row names outside of the inner loops in 1 step rather than at each inner step.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative path outside of R. I use `qsub` to submit parallel `R` jobs. I use a job by file. Each R function write a line of the data frame in a common file, for instance with:

```
 line=paste(paste("\"", name, "\"", sep=''), res, sep=', ')
 write(line,file=textfilename,append=TRUE)
```